# Java - url timing out

Tags: java

I am trying to download images off  website... it works great locally... but when the applet is run via web browser.. it gets cut off. For example, it downloads the images great but around 460-500... the image downloading suddenly stop.

Here's what I'm using:

```
                for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TILES; i++) {

                        try {
                System.out.println("Downloading tile " + i + " of "+NUM_TILES);
                File outputFileLocation = new File (System.getenv("APPDATA") + "\\.mystik\\tiles\\t"+i+".png");             
                String imgURL="line_tile/t"+i+".png";
                URL urlItem = new URL(imgURL);
                Image imageBR = ImageIO.read(urlItem);
                BufferedImage cpimg=(BufferedImage) imageBR;
                ImageIO.write(cpimg, "png", outputFileLocation);
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
                System.out.println("Tiles downloaded!");
```

Why is it cutting off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is it cutting off?

It is hard to say.  Have you checked the Java console in the web browser?  Are you getting an exception stacktrace?

One possibility is that the browser has decided that the applet has taken too long ... but I'm just guessing.

Comment: I think you're probably correct Stephen... and the usual remedy is to perform the download (or indeed any "potentially long running process") on a worker thread, in the background, freeing the EDT to respond to the browser... so it won't kill-off your applet on the presumtion that it's "dead", because it's "not responding" within the timout limit.

Comment: Yes, I checked the console. It randomly stops after around 400 and loads up fine. The missing tiles are shown as white.

Comment: So, what you're saying is do `Thread.sleep(10000)` before the load of tiles starts?

Comment: @Jahkr - no.  He is saying that you should do the download on a different thread; read http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html